# UnknownHostException when run on device

Tags: android, hosts, unknown-host

I got an UnknownHostException  when I run the app on the device. When in the emulator, it was fine. I did the configuration of the server and hosts file thing. But I dont know if I have to do it again. Please, any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Q: Is the address some public site that any DNS should be able to resolve?  Or a local host on your own LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Restarting the avd, copying the hosts file to the android emulator, adding the internet permission. Then the problem was solved.